# Making a table with only divs

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to make a table with only divs with cell-1 cell-2 and cell-3:

the table is fluid: `width: 90%; max-width: 960px;`

cell-1 and cell-3 are fixed: `width: 100px;`

cell-2 is fluid: width: (current table width - 200px) and can be smaller.

Just like in a table where 2 cells are fixed width and the other is fluid which covers the rest of the table width.

How to do that?

Comment: Did you try something and do you have any codes to share?

Comment: Floats or absolute positioning inside row wrappers.

Comment: show us what you have tried, then we can help you, not just asking us to do your job

Comment: Why do you want to create a table using divs instead of using, erm, tables?

Comment: Please respond to MMM or this question will probably be closed...

Answer (score 1):

While is BAD to answer without the OP actually posting some code to show us you are at least trying something, here is the solution (had something near that ready for something I was doing):

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">100</div>
        <div class="table-cell">fluid</div>
        <div class="table-cell">100</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 960px;
    border:1px solid blue; /* just for looks */
}

.table-row {
    display:table-row;
}

.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;/* just for looks */
}

.table-row > .table-cell:first-child, .table-row > .table-cell:last-child {
    width:100px;
    background-color:lightgray; /* just for looks */
}
```

[Demo @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/cPmZA/)

Comment: Unless this is purely for layout purposes I see no reason not to use a normal `table` element. Recreating a `table` using `div` just to avoid using tables is madness. However, if it _is_ for layout purposes I'd name the classes differently and I'm pretty sure you can skip the `table-row` element completely (unless of course you need more than one row).

Comment: @powerbuoy I do hope OP is going to use for layout purposes because would be dumb to put tabular data not on a table (most newbies thinks table's can't be used anywhere, which is wrong). This can be used when you don't want to use floats. Which in my opinion is the same as doing with `<table>`.. And yes, we can skip row but dunno if he needs more rows.

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant no criticism towards your reply. Was merely adding to it. I use display: table and the others often myself.